# Make TikZ provide new points when using rotate around

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, petri, topaths, automata, calc, patterns, angles, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.4,-1.125) to [out = 160, in = 20]
(-1.85,-1.1) to[out =60,in = 270]
(-1.7,-0.35) to
(-0.55,-0.35) to
(-1.55,0.4) to
(-1.4,1) to[out = 290, in = 160]
(-0.6,0.25) to[out = 90,in=285]
(-0.45,0.9) to
(-0.75,0.75) to (-1.34,1.352)
to (-0.75,2.05)
to[out=-30,in = 100] (0.75,0.75)
to[out=45,in=270] (1.1,1.325);

\begin{scope}[rotate around ={(90:(1.1,1.325)}]
\draw (-1.4,-1.125) to [out = 160, in = 20]
(-1.85,-1.1) to[out =60,in = 270]
(-1.7,-0.35) to
(-0.55,-0.35) to
(-1.55,0.4) to
(-1.4,1) to[out = 290, in = 160]
(-0.6,0.25) to[out = 90,in=285]
(-0.45,0.9) to
(-0.75,0.75) to (-1.34,1.352)
to (-0.75,2.05)
to[out=-30,in = 100] (0.75,0.75)
to[out=45,in=270] (1.1,1.325);
\end{scope}

\node[circle, fill = red, inner sep = 1pt] at (1.1,1.325){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which generates two paths for me, by rotating the first path by 90 degrees around the red dot. Is there a way for me to then easily place them into one continous path, so they are all within the same \draw ; section. I was thinking if I could get LaTeX to provide me with the new coordinates after the rotation about the point I could work from that.

Comment: Please merge your code fragment in one complete small document that we not need tow write (what you already do) from scratch. In general new code is rotated around given origin `(1.1,1.325)`.  You need to employ some basic geometry for which you can do calculation by `calc` library.  In this polar coordinates seems to handy.

Comment: @Zarko I've updated with some functional code now, and I know the calculations are simple enough to do, but my issue is if there is a smarter way to get it to provide me a fully continous path in one \draw ; command, besides me having to do manual calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just add `[rotate around ={(90:(1.1,1.325)}]` in the path, everything after it will be rotated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.4,-1.125) to [out = 160, in = 20]
(-1.85,-1.1) to[out =60,in = 270]
(-1.7,-0.35) to
(-0.55,-0.35) to
(-1.55,0.4) to
(-1.4,1) to[out = 290, in = 160]
(-0.6,0.25) to[out = 90,in=285]
(-0.45,0.9) to
(-0.75,0.75) to (-1.34,1.352)
to (-0.75,2.05)
to[out=-30,in = 100] (0.75,0.75)
to[out=45,in=270] (1.1,1.325)
[rotate around ={(90:(1.1,1.325)}]
 (-1.4,-1.125) to [out = 160, in = 20]
(-1.85,-1.1) to[out =60,in = 270]
(-1.7,-0.35) to
(-0.55,-0.35) to
(-1.55,0.4) to
(-1.4,1) to[out = 290, in = 160]
(-0.6,0.25) to[out = 90,in=285]
(-0.45,0.9) to
(-0.75,0.75) to (-1.34,1.352)
to (-0.75,2.05)
to[out=-30,in = 100] (0.75,0.75)
to[out=45,in=270] (1.1,1.325);
\node[circle, fill = red, inner sep = 1pt] at (1.1,1.325){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And since this is twice the same path, you could be looking for `insert path`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my path/.style={insert path={(-1.4,-1.125) to [out = 160, in = 20]
(-1.85,-1.1) to[out =60,in = 270]
(-1.7,-0.35) to
(-0.55,-0.35) to
(-1.55,0.4) to
(-1.4,1) to[out = 290, in = 160]
(-0.6,0.25) to[out = 90,in=285]
(-0.45,0.9) to
(-0.75,0.75) to (-1.34,1.352)
to (-0.75,2.05)
to[out=-30,in = 100] (0.75,0.75)
to[out=45,in=270] (1.1,1.325)}}]
\draw[my path,rotate around ={(90:(1.1,1.325)},my path];
\node[circle, fill = red, inner sep = 1pt] at (1.1,1.325){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```